# Difference between var someString = “Some String”, var someString: String = “Some String”, var someString = “Some String” as string

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone please explain me the difference

```
var someString = “Some String”
var someString: String = “Some String”
var someString = “Some String” as String
var someString = “Some String” as! String
var someString = “Some String” as? String
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
let someString = “Some String”
let someString: String = “Some String”
```

For this two:

There’s zero runtime efficiency difference between the two. During compilation, Swift is inferring the type and writing it in for you. But once compiled, the two statements are identical.

```
let someString = “Some String” as String
```

Means you are casting `someString` value to string if it is not string.

```
let someString = “Some String” as! String
```

Means you are forcibly casting “Some String” as a string but if it is not convertible to string then it will crash the app.

```
let someString = “Some String” as? String
```

Means you are optionally casting `“Some String”` to string means if it is not convertible to string then it will return nil but wont crash at this point.

For last 3 Statement It would compile and work but it is definitely wrong to cast String to String. there is no need to cast a `String` to `String`.

And the the last 2 `as?` and `as!` would always succeed in your case.

Consider below example:

```
let stringObject: AnyObject = "Some String"
let someString3 = stringObject as! String
let someString5 = stringObject as? String
```

This is when you will need to cast. Use `as!` only if you know it is a string. And use `as?` if you doesn't know that it will be string or not.

only force downcast with `as!` if you are sure otherwise use conditional cast like this:

```
if let someString5 = stringObject as? String {
    println(someString5)
}
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks a lot.